# Generate 12 digits unique number in java application

Tags: java, mysql

I've to store user profiles in LDAP with 12 digits unique ID, so thought of using
database by creating a sequence and accessing it in Java code(seq.nextVal()).
But our company only supports mysql, but mysql don't support sequence.

Is there a work around to achieve this using mysql.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: But I need that Id in java application so that I can assign to user profile to save it in LDAP.

Comment: Are you sure you need the ID in your app before using it to save in your database?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: yes, I'm sure I need Id.I'm not saving to DB table,,I'm saving profiles to LDAP.

Comment: You can generate the ID from your database and get it in Java application, then use it to save it in your LDAP.

Comment: You mean create a table with id ( auto increment) and query the table in Java. that sounds good but my id value should start with 100000000000(12 digits default value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL supports auto increment on INTEGER data type. Refer to

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

If you want to make the field `UNIQUE`, then you can set it as `PRIMARY KEY`.

As an example, you can use `ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT` as your field.

---

If you need this value in your Java application, you can:

- Generate the id in your MySQL database
- Get the value in your Java application
- Use the value to save it in your LDAP

As a test, this will assure that all your elements have 12 digits (based in your last comment):

```sql
CREATE TABLE uniqueids(id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT);

INSERT INTO uniqueids VALUES(100000000000);

INSERT INTO uniqueids VALUES(null);

SELECT *
FROM uniqueids
```

Tested on MySQL 5.0

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c508f/1

Comment: So everytime I want a unique number, then I've to call insert to table first and get the ID..is that right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Another strategy could be update this ID manually by incrementing it by 1 and then retrieving this value.

Comment: If you can, then instal PostgreSQL and test the `SEQUENCE` datatype: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html